# Does firebase handle email/pass authentication encryption?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am thinking of using Firebase email/password authentication and I was wondering does Firebase handle all the encryption? Esecially from client to server?

Answer (score 1):

Credentials are sent from the Firebase SDK in your app/web page to the server over an SSL connection. So they're encrypted on a lower level already.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is, like described below

[image: Firebase - authentication]

Comment: Can you add a link to the page rather than a screenshot? The screenshot isn't all that helpful for answering the OP question